# Is this code right to estimate the empirical of the probability of the sample mean greater than epsilon?

Tags: python, numpy

For random variables `X` sampled from Uniform[0,1] with sample size `N=100`, fix a `epsilon=0.01`. My estimator is sample mean of `X` denoted by `sample`.

I want to simulate the empirical of `Prob(|sample|>epsilon)`, which is that `mean(|sample^i|>epsilon)` for each sample `N` with replication `M=30`. My code is as follows.

```
np.random.seed(10001)
N=100
M=30
ep=0.01
sample=np.zeros(M)
prob=np.zeros(N)

for i in range(0, N):
  for j in range(0, M):
     x=np.random.random_sample(N)
     sample[j]=np.mean(x)
  prob[i]=np.mean(sample)
```

```
k=np.linspace(0,100,num=100)
plt.plot(k, prob)
```

The output is
[image]

Is this code right to estimate the empirical of the probability of the sample mean greater than epsilon?

Comment: Maybe [Stat Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
N = 1000
M = 300
ep = .01
```

The following line generate a random sample of size `N` in the interval `[0,1)` and repeats the experiment for `M` times

```
X = np.random.random_sample((M,N))
```

The following line computes frequency of `x>ep` in each of the `M` experiments:

```
(X>ep).mean(axis=1)
```

If you want to graph the empirical probability `x>ep`:

```
plt.hist((X>ep).mean(axis=1))
plt.show()
```

[image]